# relation of boundary and connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a connected topological space, $U$, $V\in X$ two non-disjoint open subsets none of which contains the other one. Prove that if their boundaries $Fr(U)$ and $Fr(V)$ are connected, then $Fr(U)\cap Fr(V)\neq\emptyset$.

I've tried that since $X$ is connected, and $U, V$ are proper subsets of $X$, then $Fr(U)$ and $Fr(V)$ are not empty. And also since $Fr(U)$ and $Fr(V)$ are connected, then $Cl(U)$ and $Cl(V)$ are connected. Then $Cl(U)\cap V\neq\emptyset$, and $Cl(U)\cap (X-V)\neq\emptyset$, then $Cl(U)\cap Fr(V)\neq\emptyset$, but I can not see this goes anywhere, any help, thanks!

Comment: what are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Should be U and V, typed wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After edit:** Still false. Consider two points $x,y\in X=\Bbb R^n$, and then $U=X\setminus\{x\}$ and $V=X\setminus\{y\}$.

---

**Before edit:** False. Consider $X=\Bbb R^2$, $U=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $V=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, (x-1)^2+y^2<1\}$.

Comment: typed wrong, sorry, the question should be $Fr(U)\cap Fr(V)\neq\emptyset$